# Android Studio Kotlin - @Volatile annotation does not show as an annotation

Tags: android, kotlin

I am following a tutorial [Android Development(Kotlin) Full Course For Beginners 2022](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BCSlZIUj18Y&t=257s) on Youtube and duplicating his code. There is a section thatuse the annotation called **@Volatile** and I noticed it was a common used annotation during Android Application programming. However, the annotation is not available as shown in the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsoSe.png). I try to add in a dependency for kotlin.jvm by adding `implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm:org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm.gradle.plugin:1.7.0-Beta'` in the gradlie.build(module) file to make the **@Volatile** annotation work but it seems like this is not the correct way and it comes out as an error shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXlyi.png). My question is why the **@Volatile** annotation does not show as an available annotation and what should I do to make it available? Based on what I understand it should be available automatically even if i didn't add in any new dependency. Please correct me if I am wrong and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Successfully solve the issue while solving another issue. The solution is to adding `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.7.10"` in the gradle.build file. However, I do not understand why is this work and appreciate if someone can answer me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the other answer to work. After playing around with my build.gradle(module) file, I discovered that I needed to update the version on my "kotlin-stdlib-jdk". I am using room 2.4.3 and I had to set my stdlib-jdk version to "kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20" for the @Volatile annotation to show as an annotation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I update my ***build.gradle(app)***, at part implementation `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1`, I don't know why but the `@Volatile` magically works.

Answer (score 0):

@Volatile annotation should be built-in to the Kotlin library, as you mentioned, so it should be available for use without any additional dependencies.

Could it be that the placement of @Volatile is incorrect? @Volatile should be used on variables.

Alternatively, if you are using Android Studio, try clicking on the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" icon in the toolbar to perform Gradle synchronization.

If you still can't use the @Volatile annotation, check the Kotlin and Android versions associated with the tutorial you're following. There may be differences between the environment at the time the tutorial was written and the current environment, which could be the cause of the issue.